# Alternatives to TOR Onion Browser for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, tor

I'm running Windows XP professional and yes, I realize support has ended long ago. I have been trying to run TOR but it does not run properly. What are the alternatives that will run onion websites in the Windows XP OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

> https://alternativeto.net/software/onion-cab/ - Onion.cab is a TOR 2 Web Proxy. With onion.cab you can visit .onion-sites without having TOR installed. Full Anonymity! Faster than TOR! With TOR-SearchEngine!
>
> https://alternativeto.net/software/tor2web/ - A proxy allowing access to Tor hidden services.